# Using a wrapper class to hide functions

Tags: php, data-structures

A colleague of mine preferes to encapsulate all of the PHP functions behind classes. His justification seems to be that if its in a class its going to be easier to change if they ever update the code. My concern after looking at his code is I have no clue what might be happening, or why things might error out. Additionally if it were in class form I'd prefer a a static function to what he is doing as it seems to me would be better practice.

For example instead of:

```
$var = filter_var('0755', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

He would have:

```
class Filter {
     public function filterInt($var) {
           return filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
     }
}

$filter = new Filter();
$var = $filter->filterInt('0755');
```

Which way would be better practice? better for long term performance? better for understanding?

Comment: a class takes longer to initiate then a single function, but for scalability using classes with a proper tried and tested design pattern/s classes/oop win over procedural, tho procedural can be easyier to understand for early devs, but thats not the point, btw its not obfuscate its encapsulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding functionality in methods is good practice, [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) explains quite well, why that's the case.

If you ever want to change the `filterInt`, e.g. add upper and lower bounds, you are way better off if you have encapsulated it.

- less code lines to be changed
- easier to test against
- ..

Answer (score 0):

For only one method like your example, it does not make much sense.

It start to make sense if you use it to group all your filter function here, you could have `Filter::filterDeliveryAdress` and then, anytime you have to filter something you might remember that you already have a function for this. So if you filter function is for exsample not accurate enough, you can fix it in the class to get it fixed in all your code.

Of course here a static function would be better, it's even easier to use.

If, as I think, it's only for grouping related function and your using PHP >= 5.3, namespace would be more appropriate.